# USB headset microphone not usable in settings, but still detected by alsa

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, pipewire

welcome to another episode of the never-ending story: troubleshooting audio...

I have an USB3 headset (Jabra Connect 4h). Speakers work fine, but microphone is not usable:

- alsa seems to see it:

➜ `arecord -l`

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: Audio [Thunderbolt 4 Dock Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 2: Camera [Auto Focus Camera], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 3: J4h [Jabra Connect 4h], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

but PulseAudio does not list it in `pavucontrol-qt` input devices tab.

Piprewire is no more lucky:

➜ `wpctl status`

```
Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      48. Built-in Audio                      [alsa]
 │      59. Thunderbolt 4 Dock Audio            [alsa]
 │      80. Auto Focus Camera                   [alsa]
 │     103. Jabra Connect 4h                    [alsa]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │      53. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 1.00]
 │      61. Thunderbolt 4 Dock Audio Analog Stereo [vol: 0.40]
 │  *   79. Jabra Connect 4h Digital Stereo (IEC958) [vol: 0.65]
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │      54. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 1.00]
 │      58. Thunderbolt 4 Dock Audio Analog Stereo [vol: 0.97]
 │  *   75. Auto Focus Camera Analog Stereo     [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
```

So... what is the way to troubleshoot, and hopefully solve, this ?